# grep - put part of string into variable

Tags: unix, command-line, grep

I'm using swfdump to be able to get the ID number of an audio file. Here is what I'm using:

swfdump -D /Users/home/folder/file.swf | grep -i mp3

That is outputting:
[00e]     28999 DEFINESOUND defines id 0006 (MP3 22Khz 16Bit mono)

What I need is the id #..in this case it is 0006. i want that number in a variable. Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: What do you mean "in a variable" in this context?  Environment variable?

Comment: I'm using it in a shell script and I will use that id number variable in another command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
the_id=`swfdump -D /Users/home/folder/file.swf | grep -i mp3 | cut -d' ' -f6`
```

Comment: This seems to work but I have the wrong id...the above gives me 28999...and I want the 0006.

Answer (score 1):

```
var=$(swfdump -D /Users/home/folder/file.swf | sed '/MP3/s/.*id //;s/ (.*//')
```

or Bash

```
$ s=$(swfdump -D /Users/home/folder/file.swf)
$ var=${s/(MP3*}
$ echo $var
0006
```

Comment: Unfortunately, neither of these work...

swfdump dumps all the decompiled swf contents. The first example doesn't narrow it down at all. The second example cuts the decompiled swf contents down a bit but still no id.